# Git - local branches , update from remote

Tags: git

I've setup a git environment (mo github)  where I have

- remote: one branch
- local: a master branch and a featureX branch that I work on it/

Now, on remote some teammate pushed on remote  a feature on remote that I want on my feature branch.

Which are the right steps to do that?

Comment: Start with "git pull"

Comment: In which branch? In my feature branch?

Answer (score 2):

The concept of remote and local branches can sometimes be a little bit confusing in the beginning. 
If you want to keep your local branch "master" in sync with the remote branch git pull suggested in another answer here is a good way of doing so. There is also another way of keeping up with the remote branch while still working on your featureX branch without leaving the branch: merge your friends changes directly from the remote branch.

```
git fetch
git merge origin/master
```

Answer (score 1):

What it worked for me

- In the local master branch: `git pull`
- in the local feature branch: `git merge master`

What it did not work for me:

- `git pull` in the local feature branch

Note:

It would  have been great that people who down-voted my question would have also answered to this question.